# Can a variable have two values?

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to give a variable two values?

```
ImageView imageView  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1) && itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
```

Comment: No. You might want to describe what you are trying to do instead.

Comment: Of course not. An `ImageView` is a single `ImageView`. This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Why do you want to give the two values?

Comment: Why not use _two_ variables, an array, or a `List`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you might be looking for an `or` solution instead of an `and`. An `and` of views makes no sense.

However, you could default to a second view if a first view cannot be found:

```java
imageView = Optional.ofNullable(itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1))
                    .orElse(itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2));
```

Comment: I like it, it's a clever one.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **NO**

but, it depends where, you can manage to do different things:

```
Pair<ImageView, ImageView>  imageViewPair  = new Pair<>(itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1), itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2));
```

that could be an option, if you want multiple:

```
List<ImageView> images = Arrays.asList(itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1), itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2), ..., ...);
```

and also with `Optional` as @Saswat Padhi you have another one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case - no. However it is possible to hold multiple values in variable that is a collection.

Answer (score -1):

No you cant do that , Image view should be defined one time , if you need easy way for binding views you can use butter knife
[click here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife)